# Is it possible to hide files on OSF?

Tags: open-science

Is there a way or option to hide a particular file in a repository on OSF (Open Science Framework) from users who access the repository with a view-only link?

Comment: So you want to be open without being open? What is the use case?

Comment: Would this work with component-level privacy settings as described [here](https://help.osf.io/article/285-control-your-privacy-settings)?

Comment: @JonCuster, the use case is that there are pdf files revealing the authors' names, which should be excluded from blinded review where the reviewers only receive a view-only link.

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution suggested by @Anyon does not work for hiding individual files from people with access only via view-only links.

Comment: Is not the solution to not upload such files until after acceptance of the paper?